# How constructor in controller rewrite into provider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this controller to work with MailChimp:

```
class MailchimpController extends Controller
{
    private $MC_API_KEY;
    private $MailChimp;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CHIMP_KEY = getenv('CHIMP_KEY');
        $this->MailChimp = new MailChimp($this->CHIMP_KEY);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->MailChimp->get('test');
    }

    public function show($test)
    {
        return $this->MailChimp->get("test/$test");
    }
}
```

How do I rewrite this constructor to service provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider@register:

Lets not deal with the 'env' and pull that from the config (for caching reasons).

```
$this->app->bind(MailChimp::class, function ($app) {
    return new MailChimp($app['config']['services']['mailchimp']['key']);
});
```

Controller constructor:

```
public function __construct(MailChimp $mailchimp) {
    $this->mailchimp = $mailchimp;
}
```

For a facade you 'could try' to just use a [Real-time Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#real-time-facades).

```
use Facades\SomeNamespace\MailChimp as MailChimp;

public function blah()
{
    MailChimp::get(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in `register()` bind class to service container:

```
$this->app->bind(MailChimp::class, function () {
    return new MailChimp(getenv('CHIMP_KEY'));
});
```

Now in your controller you have 2 options:

First is to resolve it via app helper:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->MailChimp = app(MailChimp::class);
}
```

Or use dependency injection:

```
public function __construct(MailChimp $mailchimp)
{
    $this->MailChimp = $mailchimp;
}
```

Comment: But when I want use it in function - I get: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

Comment: sorry I didn't test it with app helper, changed code (tested with 5.5)

Comment: If I understand in service provider bind "MailChimp::class" as "new Mailchimp...", it's true? And can i in my controller use like this: "MailChimp::get()"?

Comment: No. If you wish to use as `MailChimp::get()` you would need to create facade. In service provider MailChimp::class is at is. This will return string of a class for example `App\Mail\MailChimp`